# Realtime chat room

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, firebase, chat

This is a really simple chat room that I've made using Firebase. Before I take it to the next level I want to know if there is anything I can improve right now. Since I'm new to Firebase I don't know a whole lot about it so any pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://insertnamehere.firebaseio.com/');

//Set a max limit of entries to 100
dataAddQuery = myDataRef.limit(100);

dataAddQuery.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
});

//Adds a scrollbar when 26 messages have been written so that it stays within the container
dataRemoveQuery = myDataRef.endAt().limit(26);

dataRemoveQuery.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    removeChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
});

document.getElementById("messageInput").addEventListener("keypress",(function (e) {

    //When ENTER is pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var name = document.getElementById('nameInput').value;

        if (name.length > 18) {
            alert('Please enter a shorter name'); //The alert is temporary
        }
        else {
            var text = document.getElementById('messageInput').value;

            if (text.length > 450) {
                alert('Your message is too long'); //The alert is temporary
            }
            else {
                myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
                document.getElementById('messageInput').value = "";
            }
        }
    }
}))

function displayChatMessage(name, text) {

  var newMessage = document.createElement("div");
  newMessage.innerHTML = "<b>" + name + "</b> : " + text;
  document.getElementById("messagesDiv").appendChild(newMessage);
}

function removeChatMessage(name, text) {
  document.getElementById("messagesDiv").removeChild(document.getElementById("messagesDiv").firstChild)

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id='container'>
    <div id='header'>Have a chat</div> 
    <div id='messagesDiv'></div>

    <div id='inputs-holder'>
        <label for='nameInput'>Name:</label>
        <input type='text' id='nameInput'>
        <!--<span>Press enter to send your message</span> Excluded for this review -->
        <!--<button id='questionmark'>?</button> Excluded for this review -->
        <textarea type='text' id='messageInput' placeholder='Write your message here...'></textarea>   
    </div>
</div>

<!--<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>-->
<script src="chatroom.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that you've created two different Firebase references here to monitor the same data (one monitoring 100 elements and one monitoring 20). You would probably want to re-use the same ref so that they are consistent. Otherwise, when items move out of the window for your child_added list, they will not trigger child_removed calls.

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://insertnamehere.firebaseio.com/');

// Set a max limit of entries to 100
dataQuery = myDataRef.endAt().limit(100);

// Listen for items moving into our out of the display window
dataQuery.on('child_added', /* display */);
dataQuery.on('child_removed', /* remove */);
```

It also looks like your remove method wouldn't work as expected. It tries to look `messagesDiv` *inside of* `messagesDiv`, which seems incorrect.

An easier approach would be to give each chat message a unique id. With a library like jQuery, I'd use something like `data-id="<name>"`, but in vanilla JavaScript, I'd probably just go for the `id` attribute to keep things simple.

```
function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
  var newMessage = document.createElement("div");
  newMessage.innerHTML = "<b>" + name + "</b> : " + text;
  // add the id!
  newMessage.id = "message-" + name;
  document.getElementById("messagesDiv").appendChild(newMessage);
}

function removeChatMessage(name, text) {
  // remove using the id attribute
 var child = document.getElementById("message-"+name);
 document.getElementById("messagesDiv").removeChild(child);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A short review of the 'keypress' handler;

- I would make a dedicated named function for this handler, because of the size of it
- Instead of only continuing when `keyCode` is 13, I would `return` if the `keyCode` is not 13
- I would have a pattern where I call a function that takes data and updates an output array for messages

So something like this:

```
document.getElementById("messageInput").addEventListener("keypress", keypressHandler );

function keypressHandler(e) {
    //Leave unless ENTER is pressed
    if (e.keyCode != 13) {
        return;
    }
    //What should we do
    var steps = [ validateUserName, validateMessage, sendMessage ],
        output = [];

    for( var i = 0 ; i < steps.length ; i++ ){
        var f = steps[i];
        if( !f( myDataRef ) ){
          break;
      }
    }
}
```

And then create for each functionality it's own function that receives an output array, and returns `false` if processing should stop.

Comment: Question, since messageInput is a textarea, why would I need to return if the key pressed is not enter? That just means I keep writing the message and nothing happens. What's the advantage of your solution there?